# Connecting to locally hosted MySQL database using the DBI and RMySQL packages (R)

Tags: mysql, r

I am interested in exploring the possibilities for working with SQL databases from inside R. I am new to setting up and working with SQL servers, so I don't know much about it.

I set up a locally hosted MySQL server. Now, I want to connect to it from inside R. Is this even possible if the server is only hosted locally?

Connecting to a SQL database should work with the following code, but I not sure what `dbName` and `host` should be set to in the case of my locally hosted server (this is just made up example code):

```
require(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
             dbName = "database_1",
             host = "sqldb.com",
             port = 3306,
             user = "root",
             password = "1234")
```

I tried several possibilities and I always get the following error message:

```
Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't initialize character set unknown (path: compiled_in)
```

Can you help me? Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Since you have installed `MySQL` server locally you can use `host ='localhost'` in `dbConnect` function. Moreover, you can have a look at other posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849987/mysql-query-works-well-at-workbench-but-takes-too-long-in-r

Comment: Thank you! Still doesn't work, though. :( I also tried RMariaDB::MariaDB() as the driver function - also got an error message.